# Validate information on form fields generated at runtime in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to create a process that generates a form with its fields at runtime. This form is a simple form and not a Model form. It contains a number of RadioSelect fields, a TextArea, and an IntegerField.
The number of radio button fields that will be generated is determined by the data gotten from a database table. The data is in JSON which contains a list of dictionaries when parsed, and it looks like this:

```
[
  {'criteria': 'design', 'description': 'aaa, bbb'}, 
  {'criteria': 'design', 'description': 'ccc, ddd'}, 
  {'criteria': 'design', 'description': 'eee, fff'}, 
  {'criteria': 'design', 'description': 'ggg, hhh'}, 
  {'criteria': 'design', 'description': 'iii, jjj'}, 
  {'criteria': 'design', 'description': 'kkk, lll'},
]
```

In the above example, there are 6 dictionaries which means that 6 RadioSelect fields will be generated. If the JSON data contains 10 dictionaries then 10 RadioSelect fields will be generated. The TextArea and IntegerField fields are always present in the form.

When the form is submitted, I would like to validate the form and if no errors, get the data from the form, perform some operations on the data, save the data in a different database table and display the form with the saved data. If there are errors then display the form with the errors that occurred.

I would like to code this process using only one view and one template.
Here's a simplified excerpt of my code

forms.py

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        radio_choices = (
            ('0', '0'),
            ('1', '1'),
            ('2', '2'),
            ('3', '3'),
            ('4', '4'),
        )

        ratings = kwargs.pop('rating')
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(ratings, QueryDict):
            self.ratings = ratings.dict()
            # stuck here
        else:
            self.ratings = ratings
            # loop through the dict and create radio button for each of them
            for idx, rating in enumerate(self.ratings, start=1):
                field = forms.TypedChoiceField(
                    label=rating["criteria"],
                    choices=radio_choices,
                    coerce=lambda x: bool(int(x)),
                    widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                    initial=0,
                    required=False,
                )
                self.fields["criteria{}".format(idx)] = field

        self.fields["details"] = forms.CharField(
            label="Details",
            # max_length=80,
            required=False,
            widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Type any other impressions you have',
            }),
            help_text='Write any message here',
        )

        self.fields["overall_evaluation"] = forms.IntegerField(
            label="Overall Evaluation",
            max_value=4,
            min_value=0,
            required=True,
        )
```

views.py

```
from .models import Rating, Result
def formtest(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # request.POST contains a QueryDict which is immutable
        # To get a mutable object call the copy() method on request.POST??
        ratingform = ExampleForm(rating=request.POST or None) # fails here

        # call is_valid here??
        # Process data
        # Save data in Result
    else:
        rating = Rating.objects.get(pk=4).criteria
        ratingform = ExampleForm(rating=json.loads(rating))

return render(request, 'formtest.html', context={
    'form': ratingform,
})
```

When accessing the form for the first time, I can create the form without any problems but after the form is submitted the not only do I get an error, I think I will not be able to generate the labels for the RadioSelect fields.

I think the reason is that the QueryDict data in `request.POST` has a different form to that of the original list of dictionaries gotten from the database table. Here is how `request.POST` looks like

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['sfdgbif'], 'criteria1': [
'0'], 'criteria2': ['0'], 'criteria3': ['0'], 'criteria4': ['0'], 'criteria5': ['0'], 'criteria6': ['0'], 'details': ['very good product'], 'overall_evaluation': ['3']}>
```

The keys, `criteria1..criteria6`, are different from the `criteria` key in the original list of dictionaries and they only contain numbers, which are the values chosen from the radio buttons before submitting the form. 
One way might be to modify the QueryDict but I don't know if this is a good way to go about it.

How can I recreate the form with the request.POST data and check if the form is valid on submit?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I didn't pass the POST values to the form, instead, I passed it as the form's `**kwargs` argument which is completely wrong. As a result, the form could not be validated. A single code change solved my problem.

```
ratingform = ExampleForm(request.POST, rating=interview_rating)
```